# Set class methods as functions defined externally

Tags: c++, function

I am implementing a hashtable, and I have written the following (fragment of a) class definition:

```
template <typename KEY, typename VAL>
class ExtendibleHashTable {

     /* Main hash function used. Initially, the identity function. */
     size_t hash(KEY key) {
          return key;
     }
```

I want to further add a public method, that allows one to set a custom hash function. I do know about function pointers, so I tried something like this (underneath, in the same class definition):

```
     /* Set new hash. */
     void set_hash(size_t new_hash(KEY)) {
          this -> hash = new_hash;
     }
```

However, this does not compile. 
Can you tell me the best way to achieve this effect? I have looked at the `<functional>` header but it doesn't seem to be the answer I need (or maybe I haven't understood its purpose).

Comment: It is not possible to reassign member functions.  Add a function pointer as a data member of your class  (i.e.  `size_t (*func)(KEY)`).   Initialise that member to be null.   Implement your `set_hash()` as `void set_hash(size_t (*newfunc)(KEY)) {func = newfunc;}`,   implement your hash function as `size_t hash(KEY key) {return func? func(key) : key;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot replace member functions dynamically in C++. Nor can you dynamically add member functions.

You *can*, however, have a class that contains function pointers or `std:: function` objects that you can change at run-time. So, you could for example do something like this:

```
class ExtendibleHashTable {
private:
     std::function<size_t (KEY)> m_hash_func;
public:
    size_t hash(KEY key) {
        if (m_hash_func) {
            return m_hash_func(key);
        }
        return key;
    }
    void set_hash(const std::function<size_t (KEY)>& func) {
        m_hash_func = func;
    }
};
```

In the above, the `hash` function will by default just return `key` if no specific function has been set. But, if `set_hash` has been called with an appropriate hash function (free standing function, function object or lambda), then it will instead call that function and return its result.